# Two sources with joinBlock executed only once

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

Which Block should I use so that action block get called every time `first_source` posted its value,

I have tried like following and it only prints

```
8
```

But I want following output on screen.

```
8  
6
4
```

Action Block only get called once but I want it to be executed every time `first_source` posted its value.

```
TransformBlock<int, int> first_source = new TransformBlock<int, int>((val) => { return val * 2; });
TransformBlock<int, int> second_source = new TransformBlock<int, int>((val) => { return val/3; });
JoinBlock<int, int> joinBlock = new JoinBlock<int, int>();

ActionBlock<Tuple<int, int>> actionBlock = new ActionBlock<Tuple<int, int>>((valTuple) => {
    Console.WriteLine(valTuple.Item1 + valTuple.Item2);
});

var options = new DataflowLinkOptions()
{
    PropagateCompletion = true
};

first_source.LinkTo(joinBlock.Target1, options);
second_source.LinkTo(joinBlock.Target2, options);
joinBlock.LinkTo(actionBlock, options);

first_source.Post(3);
first_source.Post(2);
first_source.Post(1);
second_source.Post(6);
second_source.Complete();
first_source.Complete();
```

Comment: The `JoinBlock` joins items from each of it's targets. You're only posting one item to `second_source` so how do you expect to get 6 or 4? What are you really trying to accomplish since this seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have wrong understanding of how [`JoinBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-use-joinblock-to-read-data-from-multiple-sources) works - for some reason you think that it will return the first element from second source for all elements of first source, which is wrong. It works as `zip` operation - for each input sequences it creates tuple with corresponding items:

```
3  2  1
6  -  -
```

So, you should post additional two `6` to get results you need, or (if you really need a Cartesian product of inputs) implement it by yourself, as `TPL Dataflow` doesn't contain any out-of-box solutions for such situations.

PS: do not use `snake_casing` for variables in C#, use lower camel case instead: `firstSource` and `secondSource`.

Comment: yes you understand my Quesion right, I know joinBlock behaviour and I want cartesion product so that target block perform for each input of source when any source posted new value, I don't have good understanding of greedy and non greedy whether we can use that or some other setting in linking these blocks.

Comment: As I said, you need to implement that by yourself, there is no possibility to do that by using only base blocks